Jitbit Macro Recorder | Not proceeding to next part of macro after X iterations
So I'm having issues with a macro that i made in Jitbit. It's not switching to second part of the macro after 20 repeats. There's no issue with finding the images just proceeding to next part of macro, it will just loop image 1/2 indefinitely.
Also second part of macro works as it should on it's own.
https://prnt.sc/21mc0SmU5b_i
It's supposed to look for image 1 or image 2 if it finds it it will just continue looping for 20 times, after that proceed to next part of macro.

Use "EXIT LOOP" instead of "END REPEAT" if you want to jump out of loop at any moment.
In your example, you are ending loop which is inside double IF statement, so it won't work.
